# Timing of action using edge-trigger of clock

Tags: verilog, clock, timing

Let's say I have a code as follows:

```
always @(clock)
begin
  if (condition is met)
     a <= 0
  else if (another condition is met)
     b <= 0
end
```

I want a <= 0 at the posedge of the clock and b <= 0 at the negedge of the clock. How do I specify this?

What I'm doing right now is...

```
always @(clock)
begin
   if (condition is met)
      @(posedge clock) a <= 0
   else if (another condition is met)
      @(negedge clock) b <= 0
end
```

Comment: answer provided by Greg will do your work and the code which you were using do not work as u intended.supposing condition is met,if clock makes L-H transition,it enters always block and at the next posedge 'a' becomes zero.And i dont think this is want you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two `always` blocks. One for `posedge` and another for `negedge`.

```
always @(posedge clock) begin
  if (condition is met)
     a <= 0;
end
always @(negedge clock) begin
  if (!(condition is met) && (another condition is met))
     b <= 0;
end
```

Comment: I don't think the OP put in enough detail to answer the question - his code tests 'condition is met' on both clock edges, for example. @OP: you also need to say if you expect this to synthesise or not.